# Why are the data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, varchar

I'm trying to display a column name as well as the data from that column, but can't because of the following error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

`Convert` or `Cast` don't work in this instance.

Code:

```
select  
   CUSTOMER_ID,
   CURRENCY,
   DELIVERY_METHOD,
   CASE WHEN (COURIER_TRACKING_XML) IS NOT NULL 
          THEN dbo.GetXml(COURIER_TRACKING_XML) + 'Courier' 
   END,
   CASE WHEN BILLING_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL 
          THEN dbo.GetXml(BILLING_ADDRESS) + 'Billing' 
   END,
   CASE WHEN DELIVERY_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
           THEN dbo.GetXml(DELIVERY_ADDRESS) + 'Delivery' 
   END
from 
   WEB_ORDERS
```

Comment: Since XML is structured data and your average random `VARCHAR` is not, disallowing concatenation makes eminent sense. What does `dbo.GetXml` return and why do you want to tack on a string like `Courier` to it? Also, how exactly have you tried to use `CAST` and `CONVERT`?

Comment: If `GetXml` returns `XML` data, you cannot just concatenate it together with ` + 'Delivery'` or `+ 'Billing'` etc. .... that's what the error means. `XML` is `XML` and it's **not** a string type!

Comment: I want to tack on a string so that I can show a column name in the output window when I run the query. I'm using CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(max)) as advised by this site: http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/the-data-types-varcharmax-and-xml-are-incompatible-in-the-add-operator

Comment: You can use `AS` to name a column (`CASE WHEN ... END AS [Courier]`). Changing the column value is neither necessary nor desirable for that.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen - that's the one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), col)` to convert an XML value to varchar.

```
   CASE WHEN (COURIER_TRACKING_XML) IS NOT NULL 
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),dbo.GetXml(COURIER_TRACKING_XML)) + 'Courier'
```